# Issue when deploying with Gigalixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gigalixir

When I try to deploy with gigalixir I get this error. I don’t know why it’s so difficult to deploy elixir…

```
-----> Checking Erlang and Elixir versions
       Will use the following versions:
       * Stack cedar-14
       * Erlang 21.0
remote:  Elixir 1.9.1
-----> Using cached Erlang 21.0
-----> Installing Erlang 21.0

remote: -otp-21.zip
remote:  for generic OTP version
remote: Command '[u'docker', u'run', u'--memory-reservation=512m', u'--rm', u'-e', 
u'GIGALIXIR_SHOULD_CLEAN_CACHE=False', u'-v', u'/tmp/tmppIn5TT/sizzling-embarrassed-hound:/tmp/app', u'-v', 
u'/tmp/gigalixir/cache/sizzling-embarrassed-hound/:/tmp/cache', u'-v', 
u'/tmp/tmppIn5TT/env:/tmp/env', u'--env=USER=www-data', u'us.gcr.io/gigalixir-152404/herokuish:latest']' 
returned non-zero exit status 1
To https://git.gigalixir.com/sizzling-embarrassed-hound.git/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.gigalixir.com/sizzling-embarrassed-hound.git/'
```

Any idea of what's going on? The error log is awful...

Comment: Do you use the `Mix`, `Distillery`, or `Elixir Release` deploy method?

Comment: I'm using Distillery

Comment: Can you try clearing your build cache? Also what's in your elixir_buildpack.config? See https://gigalixir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/main.html#how-to-clean-your-build-cache

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Was it the elixir version?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just gave up

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with pushing to `gigalixir` since the `gigalixir login` command didn't save the credentials necessary for pushing to my `~/.netrc`. Make sure that your `~/.netrc` contains something like this:

```
machine api.gigalixir.com
    login your@email.com
    password some_random_password
machine git.gigalixir.com
    login your@email.com
    password some_password
```

If your `.netrc` file doesn't contain this info, run `gigalixir login` again and press `Y` when it asks you whether to save the credentials to `.netrc`. This solved it for me.

Comment: I've checked the .netrc file and everything is just fine